# Determinant in calculation of orientation in Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, determinant, orientation

Assuming not all of $y_1,..., y_n$ are zero. When $i\ne j$, define
$$
c_{ij}= \frac{2y_iy_j}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2\right)^2}
$$
and
$$
c_{ii}=\frac{-\left(\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2\right)+2y_i^2}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2\right)^2}.
$$
How to show that
$$
\det(c_{ij})>0 
$$
when $n$ is odd and
$$
\det(c_{ij})<0 
$$
when $n$ is even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the fact that for any scalar $\alpha$ and $n\times n$ matrix $A$ we have $\det(\alpha A) = \alpha^n \det(A)$ to note that the sign of $\det(c_{ij})$ is the same as the sign of $\det(b_{ij})$ where

$$
b_{ij}= 2y_iy_j
$$

for $i \ne j$ and

$$
b_{ii}=2y_i^2-\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2.
$$

Next, define $d = \sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2 = y^Ty \gt 0$ and note that

$$
\det(b_{ij}) = \det(2yy^T - d I) = (-d)^n \det\left(I - \frac{2yy^T}{d}\right).
$$

Now, by [Weinstein–Aronszajn identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity) we have

$$
\det(b_{ij}) = (-d)^n \left(1 - \frac{2y^Ty}{d}\right) = (-1)^{n+1} d^n.
$$

Therefore,

$$
\det(b_{ij})>0 
$$
when $n$ is odd and
$$
\det(b_{ij})<0 
$$
when $n$ is even. Conclusion follows from the fact that $\det(c_{ij})$ has the same sign as $\det(b_{ij})$.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I still have some question in Weinstein-Aroszajn identity. What is trace class?

Comment: It means that it is possible to define the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)). There are subtleties concerning the definition in infinite dimensions. In finite dimensions it just means that the domain and codomain of the operator have the same dimension. Equivalently, it means that the matrix of the operator is square. In our case, we see that $yy^T$ is trace class because its matrix is $n\times n$.

Comment: Thanks very much.